# AWS: Grant a user or group to full admin right to a particular VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Any idea how to grant the admin rights for a particular VPC to a user or a group in AWS IAM?

Comment: What do you mean by "full admin rights"? Rights to do what, in particular?

Comment: I mean the user can have all the rights to manipulate all    the resources in a given VPC.

Comment: Manipulating "resources in a given VPC" is different to having rights to manage the VPC itself (eg creating subnets). As per my answer, this is done by giving permissions to use certain API calls by limiting them by resource or condition. [Example on Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/a/627681/267968)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really "grant admin rights". Rather, you can control which API calls a user/group is permitted to make, and specify resources and conditions on those permissions.

For example, if you wish to control in which VPC a user is allowed to launch an instance, the policy granting use of the `RunInstances` command can specify a VPC.

For details, see: [Supported Resource-Level Permissions for Amazon EC2 API Actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources.html)